# WAMP (64bit php PHP 5.6.16) memory_limit won't change

Tags: php, wamp

In the php.ini file, setting as follows:

memory_limit = 128M

I want to change this to 512M, made the change restarted the services and phpinfo still shows 128M

Also changed it in the php.ini-production and php.ini-development files incase this was being used, restarted the services and same result.

Changes the files in the PHP 7 folder incase that was somehow affecting it but the memory limit still shows 128M

I have restarted the machine but this has had no effect.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Normally changing the php.ini file should work. Can you try the same thing in your code with ini_set function and check whether it's working ?

Comment: Most probably check whether you are editing the correct file. Multiple php installation make such type of gamble.

Comment: are you changing the .ini file which PHP says it's using when you output `phpinfo();`?